# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to cretae a JDBC connection through datasource object with DriverManagerDatasorce.each time i run my appllication am getting

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException;
>   nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] exception i have added ojdbc6 jar to
>   my classpath eventhough am getting this exception

...Any suggests what i have missed.

I also tried with basicDataSource and still got same...Is that i need to arrange any configuration in server in order to get connection.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

### Here Is My configuration :

```
<bean id="datasource"class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property> 
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:orcl"></property> <property name="username" value="SCOTT"></property>
 <property name="password" value="34268"></property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: You should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`, and that is assuming you actually have the driver on the class path.

Comment: This is my xml configurayion

Comment: <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:orcl"></property>
<property name="username" value="SCOTT"></property>
<property name="password" value="34268"></property>
</bean>

Comment: Please add the configuration in the question and not in the comment.

Comment: Have you added maven dependency for ojdbc6

Comment: Can you your maven pom.xml or build.gradle if you are using gradle ?

Comment: am using maven web app added OJDBC6 jar manually to classpath

Comment: with normal jdbc code its giving no problem...

Comment: when i tried with spring jdbc am gettig above exception

Comment: seems like existing question but previous answers not solving my prob.

Comment: getting this problem from the moment onwards i added <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

Comment: What happens without driverClassName definiton?

Comment: Am unable to connect with database

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the driver class is found in project or not by adding below test code,

```
try {
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  //on classpath
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
// not on classpath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found...
By enabling connection pool in my server successfully connected with database.
added below configuration in server context.xml and placed ojdbc jar in servers lib folder.

Thanks for effort and time....:))

```
<Resource name="DSJNDI" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        authenticate="container"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" username="SCOTT"
        password="34268" maxActiver="20" maxIdle="10"
validationQuery="SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL" />
```